# YASnippet: Remove parts of expanded snippet when exiting the current active area based on condition

Tags: yasnippet

I want to write a snippet for LaTeX sum that behaves like this:
I write "sum" and trigger snippet expansion.
"sum" becomes "\sum_{$1}^{$2} $0", with $1 being the first entry point, $2 the second one and $0 the exit point.

If I write nothing inside $1, I want to have the "_{}" part deleted and proceed to $2.
Likewise with $2.

Is such a thing possible with YASnippet or any other snippet engine? I tried putting an Elisp function that deletes the needed part if exiting with no input made but it breaks the snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an extra step (see "Nested placeholder fields" in the [manual](https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html)):

```
\sum${1:_{${2:}}}^{$3} $0
```

With the optional field: `TAB, TAB, insert field 1, TAB, insert field 2, TAB to exit.` Without the optional field: `TAB, C-d, insert field 2, TAB to exit.`

Another option is to use a function that deletes the empty field in case it finds one:

```
\sum_{$1}^{$2} ${0:$$(yas-delete-if-empty)}

(defun yas-delete-if-empty ()
  (save-excursion
    (when (re-search-backward "\\\\sum\\(_{}\\)^{.+}" (line-beginning-position) t)
      (replace-match "" t t nil 1))))
```

Comment: The first option seems nice enough, thanks!